# Report Builder Sum IF according to groups

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to add up all the 1's in the Debt Protection (Red) column, then divide by the sum of the Auto Loans and Personal Loans (blue column).

[image]

Right now I am using this formula:

```
=(sum(Fields!Debt_Protection.Value)) / sum(max(Fields!Loans.Value, "Loans"))
```

To get the sum of the Debt Protection column and divide it by the sum of the Loans group (since there is more than one group).
I'm not sure how to get the sum of just the personal and auto loans instead of the whole Loans group.
I'm thinking maybe I need to use a SUMIIF.

Here's what my report looks like now:

[image]
[image]

Comment: in whichever part you need to perform the 'filter', multiply by 1 or 0 based on the criteria, so add something like `sum(iif(Fields!MyLoanTypeField.Value = "personal" or Fields!MyLoadTypeFields.Value = "auto", 1, 0) * Fields!MyFieldToSum.Value)`

Comment: Thank you. I used 
`=(sum(Fields!Debt_Protection.Value)) / sum(iif(Fields!Loan_Description.Value = "Personal Loans" or Fields!Loan_Description.Value = "Auto Loans", 1, 0))`

Comment: OK, I was doing it from memory so was not sure if it was quite right or not. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In whichever part you need to perform the 'filter', multiply by 1 or 0 based on the criteria, so add something like

```
=sum(iif(Fields!MyLoanTypeField.Value = "personal" or Fields!MyLoadTypeFields.Value = "auto", 1, 0) * Fields!MyFieldToSum.Value)
```